# What's wrong with this eval statement in Perl?

Tags: perl, eval, libxml2

What's wrong with this `eval` statement in Perl?  I'm trying to check that the XML is valid by catching any exceptions thrown from the parsing of the file with [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lib-LibXML):

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();   #creates a new libXML object.

    eval { 
    my $tree = $parser->parse_file($file) # parses the file contents into the new libXML object.
    };
    warn() if $@;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy, $tree doesn't persist past the `eval {}`. Braces in perl as a general rule always provide a new scope. And warn requires you to provide its arguments $@.

```
my $tree;
eval { 
    # parses the file contents into the new libXML object.
    $tree = $parser->parse_file($file)
};
warn $@ if $@;
```

Comment: There's no need to declare $tree separately. The result of the eval is the last evaluated result: my $tree = eval { ... }.

Answer (score 5):

You're declaring a $tree inside the braces, which means it doesn't exist past the closing brace. Try this:

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();

my $tree;
eval { 
    $tree = $parser->parse_file($file) # parses the file contents into the new libXML object.
};
warn("Error encountered: $@") if $@;
```